# What would be a good way to separate different types of user account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Supposing various type of users, like 'normal', 'medium' and 'premium' each one with different permissions.

a kind of permission on permission.

for example:

- only a registered users can post
- a normal user can post 1 post per month
- a medium user can post 5 posts per month
- a premium user can post unlimited posts per month

and some other attributes.

what you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look at [can can](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on rolling your own "role system", then what I would logically do is create a model for a class called Role, and set up permissions and levels in that class, and have a relationship between Users and different Roles.

For example, you could have a Role object named "Normal" with attributes like allowed_posts = 1 etc.

And in your users table (in the database), you would have a column called role_id, which would be set to the ID of the normal role in your roles table.